# Four variables, how to quickly check all of them are either 1 or 0?

Tags: algorithm, logic, bit-manipulation

I have four integer variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. I want to know if all of them are of values **1** or **0**. Apparently I can use if statement to check this like:

```
if((a == 0 || a == 1) && (b == 0 || b == 1) &&
   (c == 0 || c == 1) && (d == 0 || d == 1))
{
    print(true)
}
else
{
    print(false)
}
```

It's just a bit boring to write all of that. I'm thinking if there are any methods to use bit operations to solve my issue. But for now I don't have any clue about it. Anyone can point me to the right direction? Or is there any other simpler way to check that?

Comment: why don't you just store all of them in an array and use one for loop to check? `Three or more, use a for`!

Comment: Actually it's a simplified problem extracted from the SQL world. You know there is no array in SQL.

Comment: Then please use SQL example.  Set based operations and imperative programs operate very differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, take the bitwise or, and test that:

```
int e = a|b|c|d;
return e==0 || e==1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to query for max and min value of these variables, and verify the min value is 0/1 and max value is 0/1. Max and Min are supported in SQL.

Comment: actually in this case you need to check the condition (min =0 or min =1) and (max =0 or max = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
return (unsigned int)(a | b | c | d) <= 1;
```